# jQuery webcam/flash long delay

Tags: jquery, webcam

I'm using this [jQuery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) to determine whether the user has a webcam connected.

```
<div id="webcam"></div>                         
<script>
    $("#webcam").webcam({

        mode: "callback",
        debug: function (type, string) {
            if (type == 'error'){
                alert('error');
            }
        },
    }); 
</script>
```

Thing is, it pop up's the alert only after like 5-6 seconds, while on the plugin's website you can see the message when the page loads without any delays...

What can be the issue?